# How to use AliasMatch with regular expressions

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, transfer

How can I use AliasMatch in httaccess to transfer a url like this : `example.com/userName`  to this url : `example.com/user.php?name=userName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use alias. Try this following code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /user.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks but i forgot to add a notice , what if i want to do an exception like if the visitor typped : www.example.com/page.php , i mean rewrite only if the page is not listed in the directory !